# Game in Wine causes second monitor to become over exposed

Tags: ati, wine, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors and when I run a game through Wine, it causes the *second* monitor to become over exposed and increases the sharpness quite a bit. I have played around with settings in both the game and the Ubuntu settings, but nothing seems to be working. The only way to fix the exposure is to restart my entire computer.

The primary monitor seems to be fine.

Is there a way to fix this or to at least revert it once I'm finished with the game? I'm not really sure what's going on here. Currently, I need to restart in order to fix the problem. Which is kind of a pain.

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Radeon HD 6750 w/ proprietary drivers
Game: Star Wars Galaxies
```

The white from the exposure makes the monitor hard to use.

Comment: Just to get a few things out of the way: have you tried open source drivers and what version of WINE are you running? Is this only for said game or does it always occur when playing games?

Comment: It's the most recent Wine out of the Ubuntu Software Center. It's happens with this game in Wine, Linux native Steam games are fine. I've never tried any other games in Wine. I have not tried open source drivers. (Sorry I can't get version specifics, this is for my home computer and I'm at work)

Comment: I think you should try out the open source drivers then. It's way too often driver issues :-) You can also try playing another game just to make certain the issue isn't for that game only, even though it doesn't seem to be a common problem for that title.

Comment: @Xweque Non-proprietary drivers did not work.

Comment: From wine setting enable *window mode*. How you feel now ?

Comment: You can try enabling the option "Emulate a virtual desktop" from the graphics section in "Configure Wine"

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about your setup. I'm assuming based on your post that the HD 6750 card that we are discussing here was manufactured by ATI. Is this correct or is it another manufacturer like Powercolor for instance? What ports are on the card? What are the make and model of the screens? Are they connected via Dsub, DVI, HDMI? Please help us help you by providing more complete information. Thank you!

Comment: @Xweque Make this an answer, this worked nicely. Thank you. It actually works even better now since my mouse doesn't get locked into the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the option "Emulate a virtual desktop" from the graphics section in "Configure Wine".